# How can I wrap html around the output of the_time function?

Tags: theme-development, tags, html, date-time

My current code in functions.php:

```
echo '<div class="post_date">'.the_time('d', '<div class="month">', '</div>').the_time('F', '<div class="day">', '</div>').the_time('Y', '<div class="year">', '</div>').'</div>';
```

But it only returns:

```
20April2011
```

No html around it, why? how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [this documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_time) for the usage about `the_time()`. You are not supposed to add html inside the parameter of `the_time()`. (edit: use `get_the_time()` with in string concatenation)

To solve this, try this code:

```
echo '<div class="post_date"><div class="month">'.get_the_time('F').'</div>'.'<div class="day">'.get_the_time('d').'</div><div class="year">'.get_the_time('Y').'</div></div>';
```

edit: corrected to the use of [`get_the_time()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)

Comment: That created the correct html, but the time was still outside of it.

Comment: please use `get_the_time()` for usage in strings - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time

Comment: @Michael, perfect! Unix timestamp would be perfect! Post that as answer for an accept! :D